# Different results from running Google App Script manually and by triggers

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, gmail

I want each user (at the company I work at) to log Gmail-data into (a 3rd party system) Harvest.

I distributed an Apps Script by having a html-webbapp where each individual  user starts triggers (that runs a singel function) by pressing a button.

My problem is that everything works correctly only when it runs manually. When the function is triggered, the Gmail-data is logged to my user (and not the user that runs it). I have logged on to a user (experiencing this issue) and the triggers are set up correctly. The function runs correctly when triggered manually.

Psudo-code:

```
var user = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
var gmailData = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
UrlFetchApp.fetch(
  "https://api.com",
  {
    "headers": {'Authorization':"hash of admin (my) user/pw"},
    "method": "post",
    "payload": "add data " + gmailData + " to user " + user
  }
);
```

Comment: Each user has to set up their own triggers, yours will work only for you. You either ask them to open the script editor and set it up themselves or do it inside the script when each one clicks the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webapp ran an old version with one result, and manual was current code. Updating to new version solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
```

An installable trigger (programmatically in this case) runs under the auth of the user who created the trigger and `getEffectiveUser()` returns the auth'd user for the instance of the script in process.

Comment: No change.  The function post to the intended user only when run manually.